# Why isn't he player movement working for the left key and is working for the right in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am using pygame in [replit.com](https://replit.com/) and whenever I run it, it doesn't show any errors but the left and down keys don't work. I don't understand what I did wrong.

Here's my code:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

width, height = 800, 600
backgroundColor = 33, 33, 33
color = (0, 128, 255)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
player_x = 30
player_y = -30
while True:
  screen.fill(backgroundColor)
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if(event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
      if(event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
        player_x += 10
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if(event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
      if(event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
        player_x -= 10
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if(event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
      if(event.key == pygame.K_DOWN):
        player_y += 10
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(player_x, 30, 60, 60))
  pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, you have to modify the code in your `while` loop. There is no need for multiple `for` loops here, just check for the user input in only one `for` loop. Also at the second-from-last line in the `while` loop, you haven't considered the y-axis movement of the player, i.e. `player_y`.

Finally, just in the line above the `while` loop, set the y-coordinate of the player to `30` instead of `-30` so that it appears completely on the screen.

```py
player_y = 30
while True:
    screen.fill(backgroundColor)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if(event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
            if(event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
                player_x += 10

            if(event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
                player_x -= 10

            if(event.key == pygame.K_DOWN):
                player_y += 10

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (player_x, player_y, 50, 50))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Also one more thing, I have to press the keys like multiple times. How do I fix that?

Comment: You can open a new question for this one, as you cannot ask any questions or comment answers in comments

Comment: Try something like [`pygame.key.set_repeat(500, 50)`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.set_repeat). In this example after half a second, key press events will be repeated every fifty milliseconds.